# How to check if the string contains in a list and if the inputted answer is on my appended list?

Tags: python

I am having a problem comparing two words. For example, if I input the singular form, I don't want the plural form to be accepted.

```
with open('filename') as f:
     text = [line.strip().upper() for line in f]

ans= [] #right answer will append 

fruit = ['APPLE', 'ORANGE', 'BANANA'] #this list is also the same as my text file but in my text file, I include their plural forms.

fruit_contains= any(fruit in input_answer for fruit in fruit) #To check if the string contains in a list.

input_answer = input(str(i + 1) + '. ').upper()

if input_answer in text: #condition to check if the answer is on the text file
   if input_answer in fruit and fruit_contains: #condition to check if the inputted answer is on the fruit list.
      print("The word is repeated")
```

If I inputted, Apple already, I don't want the Apples to be accepted and append in my list. Vice versa.

**fruits.txt**:

```
APPLE
APPLES
ORANGES
ORANGE
BANANA
BANANAS
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will help:

```py
# This is your answer list but as a set instead. This allows you to maintain unique values only
ans = {}

# This is your list of non-pluralized fruits
fruits = ['APPLE', 'ORANGE', 'BANANA']

# This is your list of pluralized fruits
pluralized_fruits = [f'{fruit}S' for fruit in fruits]

with open('filename.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    
    # Read through the file of fruits and create another list to work with
    file_list = [row for row in reader]

# Iterate through the pluralized fruits and remove them from the file list if they exist
for fruit in pluralized_fruits:
    if fruit in file_list:
        file_list.remove(fruit)

# Find all the matches of fruit in the file list and append them to your ans list
for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit in file_list:
        ans.add(fruit)

# This is where you convert the ans set to a list. At this point it is completely deduped and should only contain non-pluralized fruit values.
ans = list(ans)
```